# What is this vine?

Tags: identification, vines

What is this vine?  I live in TX near San Antonio, it sprouts little flowers and then has these round black berries.  I really want to know because this vine has a mind of its own and will attach itself to items and grow.  Thank you all for your help I have been trying to identify for over a year.  I don't believe it is a

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site!! It looks like your last sentence is unfinished. You were saying what you don't think it looks like something but that part is gone. Would you please add that to your question? Also, do you have a picture of it when it's flowering? That would help with the identification. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking at this image on and off all day, trying to remember what it is. Luckily, it's now come to mind; it looks like Malabar Spinach, or more specifically, this particular  one's Basella rubra var. rubra. It's a vining plant with quite nutritious, edible leaves that are a bit like spinach, has white flowers, dark berries later on. Image and info here https://www.seedman.com/vine.htm but you'll need to scroll down a fair way - it's further down, under perennial vines. Frost tender and is also grown for purely ornamental reasons.

Comment: You got it, Bamboo. I had no idea Malabar spinach formed dark small berries! The vine site is nice too. Thinking of all the different vines I'd love to have practically makes me drool.